# Java generic cast, non direct

Tags: java, generics, casting, classcastexception

I found something strange about the casts in Java, i never saw that before.
The cast is actually not done where you've programmed it in a generic method.

Testing the strange thing.

On a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String,Object> map = ...
map.put("hello", "World");
System.err.println((Integer)map.get("hello")); //  -----> ClassCastException
```

On a map Wrapper

```
MapWrap wrap = ...
wrap.put("hello", "World");
System.err.println(wrap.get("hello",Integer.class)); // -----> don't cast, print World (i guess because println receives an Object reference but the cast should be done before that).
System.err.println(wrap.get("hello", Integer.class).toString()); // -----> print World + ClassCastException
```

Code of methods:

```
private <T> T get(String key, Class<T> c){
    return (T)map.get(key);
}

private Object get(String key){
    return map.get(key);
}
```

Does someone know if that mechansim has a name or know something about it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The cast:

```
(T) map.get(key);
```

doesn't do anything at all because of type erasure. The method `MapWrap.get()` will get erased to:

```
private Object get(String key, Class<T> c){
    return map.get(key);
}
```

which will always work. A cast to Integer would only be inserted where you assigning the result of this method to, and since in the first `MapWrap` example you're passing it to a method that expects an Object parameter, this doesn't happen.

In the second case, you're trying to call the method `Integer.toString()`, so a cast to Integer gets inserted, and fails.

You're already passing in the class object, the correct way to do a "generic cast" is this:

```
private <T> T get(String key, Class<T> c){
    return c.cast(map.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Types parameters are erased upon compilation. So a cast such as `(T)` becomes `(Object)` in the executable, hence the first behavior you're getting.

Type parameters are used only to perform compile-time typing and typechecking.

On the second line however, I think the compiler generates a call to the `Integer.toString()` method, so a cast is needed, hence the exception.

See: [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call this : "templates in Java are a pain" ;-).

The line :

```
System.err.println(wrap.get("hello",Integer.class));
```

Is using the method println(Object obj), so there is no type problem as nobody is actually checking the type of the return object for wrap.get

In the second case :

```
System.err.println(wrap.get("hello", Integer.class).toString());
```

It's the toString() of the Integer that is called, and there you got with your class cast exception.

Unfortunatly as Chris is pointing Java is erasing the type from a template but remember is still there in the methods (maybe)

Comment: You could also call this "Java generics are nothing like C++ templates" ;) Seriously, it's best not to think of generics in C++ terms. They really are fundamentally quite different.

Comment: I know but it's a real pain once you try doing something more than the basic.. and on top we have the lack of support for basic types (int,floats). Great for perfs

Comment: @icCube Java's generics are actually somewhat overengineered for what they're supposed to enable. Which is making the existing Collections API and similar use cases typesafe. And since Java's collections couldn't handle primitive types efficiently before generics, it's not like any performance was lost. (With type erasure, they also couldn't be made to handle them efficiently. .NET chose to use reification instead of type erasure, but the cost was having to create a new collections API, and that a lot of legacy APIs – like most of ASP.NET – weren't and can't be updated to use generics.)

Comment: As example, are you going to implement the binary seach algo or others for each basic type ? that's what we're doing currently.. yes sometimes we want the vm to create new code (yes something like the old macro). Java has a lot of great thinks but they are sooo stubborn and look as never taking seriously math-science field problems.